# Unsafepointer adjustment for Swift 4

Tags: swift3, swift4, unsafe-pointers, nsnetservice

I have not found a solution how i can adjust the following lines (error) to Swift 4. Regarding to documents, withUnsafePointer method should be used but i could not find a way to add addressBytes.bytes into code.

[image]

```
func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
    //service.addresses - array containing NSData objects, each of which contains an appropriate
    //sockaddr structure that you can use to connect to the socket
    for addressBytes in sender.addresses!
    {
        var inetAddress : sockaddr_in!
        var inetAddress6 : sockaddr_in6?
        //NSData’s bytes returns a read-only pointer (const void *) to the receiver’s contents.
        //var bytes: UnsafePointer<()> { get }
        let inetAddressPointer = UnsafePointer<sockaddr_in>(addressBytes.bytes)
        //Access the underlying raw memory
        inetAddress = inetAddressPointer.memory

        if inetAddress.sin_family == __uint8_t(AF_INET) //Note: explicit convertion (var AF_INET: Int32 { get } /* internetwork: UDP, TCP, etc. */)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if inetAddress.sin_family == __uint8_t(AF_INET6) //var AF_INET6: Int32 { get } /* IPv6 */
            {
                let inetAddressPointer6 = UnsafePointer<sockaddr_in6>(addressBytes.bytes)
                inetAddress6 = inetAddressPointer6.memory
                inetAddress = nil
            }
            else
            {
                inetAddress = nil
            }
        }
        var ipString : UnsafePointer<Int8>?
        //static func alloc(num: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
        let ipStringBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
            if (inetAddress != nil)
        {
```

Answer (score -2):

EDITED

Here's an example of using "withUnsafePointer" with swift 4.2 in Xcode 10 on a sockaddr.  I actually use two nested "withUnsafePointer" closures because I need two unsafe pointers.

I had to set "swift compiler -> code generation -> exclusive access to memory" to "no enforcement" to get this to work.

Note that using sendto() to send raw packets requires running the program as root (sudo for example)

```
let sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)

// I have a custom sockaddr extension which fully initializes my sockaddr
guard var socka = sockaddr(ipv4string: "1.1.1.1", port: 0) else { fatalError() }

// I have a custom struct that generates my icmp packet and calculates the checksum
var mypacket = IcmpEchoRequest()

let result2 = withUnsafePointer(to: &mypacket) { mypacketPointer in
    let result = withUnsafePointer(to: &socka) { sockaPointer in
        let sendResult = sendto(sockfd, mypacketPointer, mypacket.length, 0, sockaPointer, socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.size))
        print("sendResult \(sendResult)")
    }
}
```